# MySQL user password vs authentication_string

Tags: mysql, permissions, mariadb

I run following commands:

```
CREATE USER 'dbuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD('mypass');
CREATE USER 'dbuserx'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD('mypass');
SET PASSWORD FOR 'dbuser'@'%' = PASSWORD('mypass');
```

And that results in:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select host, user, password,authentication_string from mysql.user;
+------------------+---------+-------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| host             | user    | password                                  | authentication_string                     |
+------------------+---------+-------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| %                | dbuser  |                                           | *6C8989366EAF75BB670AD8EA7A7FC1176A95CEF4 |
| %                | dbuserx | *6C8989366EAF75BB670AD8EA7A7FC1176A95CEF4 |                                           |
+------------------+---------+-------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
```

Is this proper? I read there is PAM in MariaDB by default, but why user creation does not store password in `authentication_string` right from start?

Could someone explain the difference and possible problems with this?

Mariadb 10.3

Comment: As stated by manuals `CREATE USER` syntax is the next: `IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'hash_string' (no patentheses around pass string). Here PASSWORD isn't a function call but lexical part of the query.

Answer (score 2):

All of your `CREATE USER` syntax is 'backwards'.  In the "native password" scheme:

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'se211604p'@'localhost'
               IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*6C8989366EAF75BB670AD8EA7A7FC1176A95CEF4';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE USER 'se211604m'@'localhost'
               IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select user, host, password from user where user like 'se2%';
+-----------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
| user      | host      | password                                  |
+-----------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
| se211604p | localhost | *6C8989366EAF75BB670AD8EA7A7FC1176A95CEF4 |
| se211604m | localhost | *6C8989366EAF75BB670AD8EA7A7FC1176A95CEF4 |
+-----------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+

mysql> SELECT PASSWORD('mypass');
+-------------------------------------------+
| PASSWORD('mypass')                        |
+-------------------------------------------+
| *6C8989366EAF75BB670AD8EA7A7FC1176A95CEF4 |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: But does it pose any kind of problems in future?

Comment: @Gacek - MySQL is moving away from "native password" into various PAM alternatives.  Is that the kind of 'future problem' you are asking about?

Comment: More like, if I use `CREATE USER` should I follow it with `SET PASSWORD` to ensure that pass is stored in auth field instead of password field. Or should I not care about it and keeping password `password` field will not pose any problems?

Answer (score 1):

According to the page

[mysql.user Table](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mysqluser-table/)

at the very bottom:

> When the **plugin** column is empty, MariaDB defaults to authenticating
>   accounts with either the *mysql_native_password* or the
>   *mysql_old_password* plugins. It decides which based on the hash used in
>   the value for the **Password** column. When there's no password set or
>   when the 4.1 password hash is used, (which is 41 characters long),
>   MariaDB uses the *mysql_native_password* plugin. The *mysql_old_password*
>   plugin is used with pre-4.1 password hashes, (which are 16 characters
>   long).
>
> MariaDB also supports the use of alternative authentication plugins.
>   When the **plugin** column is not empty for the given account, MariaDB
>   uses it to authenticate connection attempts. The specific plugin then
>   uses the value of either the **Password** column or the
>   **authentication_string** column to authenticate the user.

There may or there may not be PAM (pluggable authentication module) authentication. A number of implementations exist, see:

[Password, Authentication and Encryption Plugins](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/password-authentication-and-encryption-plugins/)

So for example:

```
SELECT user, host,
  CONCAT(SUBSTR(password,1,5),':',LENGTH(password)) 
   AS pass,
  CONCAT(SUBSTR(authentication_string,1,5),':',LENGTH(authentication_string)) 
   AS auth,
  plugin
  FROM user;
```

gives

```
+---------------+------------+----------+----------+-----------------------+
| user          | host       | pass     | auth     | plugin                |
+---------------+------------+----------+----------+-----------------------+
| root          | %          | *687E:41 | *667F:41 | mysql_native_password |
| joe.bloggs    | %          | *E123:41 | *E1E9:41 | mysql_native_password |
| chloe.price   | %          | *FFA0:41 | :0       |                       |
| max.caulfield | %          | *981D:41 | :0       |                       |
| doge          | %          | *A6B1:41 | :0       |                       |
+---------------+------------+----------+----------+-----------------------+
```

The last three users have no plugin configured, so the value of column **password** counts. As the values therein are strings of length 41 (which is actually the maximum, the type of that column being `char(41)`), the *mysql_native_password* plugin is used.

The first two users are forcibly authenticated using the *mysql_native_password* plugin. It is left unspecified whether that plugin gets its input from the **password** column or the **authentication_string** column in case it needs more flexibility; it depends on the implementation!  As **authentication_string** is of type `TEXT`, there can be a lot of plugin-specific stuff in there, from [SHA-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) hashes longer than 41 characters to possibly whole certificate chains.

In the present case, there does not seem to be a need to have the password hash additionally in column *authentication_string*.